# Template not rendered in Vue served by Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js

I have a Django app for backend, which renders templates with Vue as frontend. My view code in django has the following parts:

```
# thing/views.py
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('thing/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render({}, request))

# thing/urls.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]

# some other files that complete the project are not included
```

In `index.html` there is the following code:

```
<div id="app">
    <p v-if="quotaRemaining > -1">
        Remaining: {{ quotaRemaining }}
    </p>
</div>

<script>
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            quotaRemaining: 42,
        },
    });
</script>
```

The only thing that is being rendered when I access this page is:

> Remaining:

While I would expect it to be

> Remaining: 42

Why is my Vue template not being rendered correctly when served by Django? How do I make it work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Django has its own [template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/), which has a concept of [variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/#variables). It treats `{{ quotaRemaining }}` as a Django variable, and processes it even before it gets to the frontend (to Vue). There are at least a couple of solutions.

1. Surround Vue related code with [`{% verbatim %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) tag:

> Stops the template engine from rendering the contents of this block tag. A common use is to allow a JavaScript template layer that collides with Django’s syntax.

```
    {% verbatim %}
    <p v-if="quotaRemaining > -1">
        Remaining: {{ quotaRemaining }}
    </p>
    {% endverbatim %}
```

2. Customize Vue [delimiters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters) and use these delimiters in your client code:

   ```
    <!-- template code -->
    <p v-if="quotaRemaining > -1">
        Remaining: ${ quotaRemaining }
    </p>

    // js code
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        delimiters: ['${', '}'],
        data: {
            quotaRemaining: 42,
        },
    });
   ```

Comment: One could also use `{{{{ quotaRemaining }}}}` if it's an occasional thing...

Comment: @JonClements, nice one, but didn't compile: `Could not parse the remainder: '{{ quotaRemaining' from '{{ quotaRemaining'`

Comment: Oh yeah... ignore me then... not sure what templating language I'm thinking of or if I've just somehow dreamt that up :)